# Accessing an array item by index in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
PROJECT_TYPES="iPad iPhone"
ANT_TARGET_NAMES="ipadf ipaf"

INDEX=0

for PROJECT_TYPE in $PROJECT_TYPES; do

echo "${PROJECT_TYPE} => ${ANT_TARGET_NAMES[$INDEX]}"

let "INDEX++"
done
```

This displays the following lines:

```
iPad => ipadf ipaf
iPhone =>
```

How can I change the code so it displays:

```
iPad => ipadf
iPhone =>  ipaf
```

???

Thanks in advance

Mike

Comment: `foo="bar baz"` creates a string with the contents `bar baz`. In certain contexts, strings can be split into sequences because of the way they're interpolated (whitespace splitting), but they are not lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is:

```
INDEX=0
PROJECT_TYPES=(iPad iPhone)
ANT_TARGET_NAMES=(ipadf ipaf)

for PROJECT_TYPE in ${PROJECT_TYPES[*]} 
do 
echo "${PROJECT_TYPE} => ${ANT_TARGET_NAMES[$INDEX]}"  
let "INDEX++" 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

bash 4 has associative arrays so you could write:

```
declare -A targets=([iPad]=ipadf [iPhone]=ipaf)
for project_type in "${!targets[@]}"; do
  printf "%s => %s\n" "$project_type" "${targets[$project_type]}"
done
```

Otherwise, declare two arrays as in ennuikiller's answer, but I would iterate over the indices directly

```
projects=(iPad iPhone)
targets=(ipadf ipaf)
for (( i=0; i < ${#projects[@]}; i++ )); do
  printf "%s => %s\n" "${projects[$i]}" "${targets[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have bash 3 here